# How should I restrict usage of methods of predefined class

Tags: java

Suppose I have created StringUtil class by extending String. Now any third party calling StringUtil can use all the methods defined for String class. How can I restrict usage of some methods?

Comment: You cannot extend `java.lang.String`. It is `final`. Are you talking about some other `String` class?

Comment: What do you mean by `restrict`? `private`/`public`?

Comment: @StavAlfi... I think she mean to remove that methods in StringUtils

Comment: One of the possible solutions to avoid calling parent methods - overide them and add custom logic. You can throw runtime exception, you can return some default value etc.

Answer (score 1):

**String** class is final, and you can't extend a final class in Java. You have to read more about Java core. For example, begin by reading https://www.w3schools.in/java-tutorial/super-final-keywords/

Also, when you want a string utility, you have several options like **Apache-Commons-Lang** or **Spring-Core** that makes your code readable and has more functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have multiple classes such that you want to give each of them access to a group of methods inside `StringUtil`, you can do the following:

If `Class1`, for example, needs only methods: `f1`, `f2`, `f3` then you could create an interface `interface1` such that exposes only `f1`, `f2`, `f3` and `Class` will receive an object of type `interface1` as a param to its constructor. `StringUtil` implements `interface1`.

Do the same for other classes so each class will be able to use only what you expose to them.

You should read also on [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

---

The interfaces:

```
interface Interface1 {
    void f1();
}

interface Interface2 {
    void f2();

    void f3();
}
```

StringUtils class:

```
class StringUtils implements Interface1, Interface2 {
    @Override
    public void f1() {

    }

    @Override
    public void f2() {

    }

    @Override
    public void f3() {

    }
}
```

The classes who use StringUtils class:

```
class A {
    private Interface1 interface1; // you can mark it as final if it's permanent.

    public A(Interface1 interface1) {
        this.interface1 = interface1;
    }
}

class B {
    private Interface2 interface2; // you can mark it as final if it's permanent.

    public B(Interface2 interface2) {
        this.interface2 = interface2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In such scenarios, however, there may be some workaround like: override the method in the base throw some expectation from it, but it will not be a real solution. My recommendation will be to use `composition` over `inheritance`. That means your `base` should `has a relationship` with `superclasses`.  For example, a let assume 2 classes A (same as your String class) and B (same as your StringUtil class).

```
class A {
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    public int square(int a) {
        return a * a;
    }
}

class B {
    A obj;

    B(A obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return obj.add(a, b);
    }
}
```

Now your class B only expose only one method `add` which `delegates` its behavior to class A's add method. Also `square` is not available on B.